# How Can I Add New Modifier Key (as Shift )

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I want to change <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd> button to a custom modifier key for adding another functions to keys as <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt-gr</kbd>.

Solution in my mind I need a new modifier key and remap <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd> to that modifier key. For example <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> for  "%" symbol. In internet I only found remap <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd> to another key. But I want to use it for my custom shortcuts.
How can I achieve that?